# How to use rendering parameters in shared component using Sitecore JSS

Tags: jss, rendering-parameters

I am using Sitecore 10 with Angular app JSS, I created shared component "Header" like that:

[image]

I have a rendering parameters `background` field, I need to add it in `yml` files of pages to be different in each page. However, when I added in home page like this:

[image]

I got this error. Please note, it was working when it was in header component not in the page.

[image]

Here is the header component definition:

[image]

Any ideas about how can I read it in pages?

Answer (score 2):

We had similar requirement to distinguish whether page is secured or not. Based on that we are then checking whether user is authenticated or not.

Implementation is using React but I think for Angular it will be similar in your case.

We have added new field of type checkbox "securedRoute" to /sitecore/definitions/route.sitecore.js:

[image]

In the route definition / yml of pages, we are setting it to true where needed as you don't need to set it to false which is default value:

[image]

And then on layout we are checking whether it is true:

[image]

In your case, you will show/hide background...

Answer (score 0):

In order for sitecore to recognize it you have to define it also in your component definition. You should edit the .js definition file located `/sitecore/definitions/components/` and you will need to add the params array and mention the expected parameters:

```
addComponent(manifest, {
  name: "Hello-World",
  displayName: "Hello-World",
  fields: [{ name: "title", type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText }],
  params: ["background"],
})
```

Comment: i did this already, and it is working when i added it in component yml, but in pages yml not working. i think this happen bz the shared component and trying to add the params in pages not in component datasource.